# gawk command from scala gives invalid character in expression error

Tags: scala, awk, syntax, process, native

Below is the sample program, that is generating a gwak command and executing it from scala.
Generated command is giving **"invalid character in expression error"**

If the same command is executed directly from macOS commandline, it works without error.

```
package org.mogli.pup.main

object GAwkSample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val  text = "hello world"
    val home = sys.env("HOME")
    val cmnd = s"gawk -i inplace 'NR==7{print " + "\"" + text + "\"" + s"}1' ${home}/FirstEg.txt"
    println(s"$cmnd")

    import sys.process._
    s"$cmnd" !
  }
}
```

Output of above scala program :-

> gawk -i inplace 'NR==7{print "hello world"}1' /Users/mogli/FirstEg.txt
>
> gawk: cmd.
>   line:1: 'NR==7{print gawk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in
>   expression

Comment: idk but why not try a simpler program and debug THAT first? Just a plain old hard-coded `{print 7}` for example and if/when that works then `{print "7"}` and so on.

Comment: Yup, tried simple commands and they worked.

Comment: There is a point earlier in the process than the script in your question between a command that works and a command that doesn't work. I'd suggest you ask for help debugging that first stage of script that doesn't work and show the immediately preceding one that does work for comparison.